# Anvil Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, anvil

I'm attempting to return a value from a row in my data table, and am getting the following error:

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (key 'GCWR')**

Here is the code snippet which is referenced in the error...

```
"""
This function gets the GCWR of the truck from the 'truck_specifications' data table
Parameters: brand, model, year, engine, drive, axle
Returns: gcwr
"""
def get_gcwr(brand, model, year, engine, drive, axle):
  gcwr_row = app_tables.truck_specifications.get(Brand=brand, Model=model, Year=year, Engine_Type=engine, Drive_Type=drive, Axle_Ratio=axle)
  gcwr = gcwr_row['GCWR']
  return gcwr
```

Some details:

- The variable 'gcwr' should return a number from a specific row in the data table based on the parameters shown above
- This previously worked, but when I began to add more data to the table it now gives me the error shown above
- I've manually reviewed the data table based on the parameters, and there is a row that meets the criteria and should return a value
- The data type for the column in the data table is 'number'

Here is the code snippet which the above function is called from...

```
"""
This function gets the truck specifications based on the users input
Parameters: none
Returns: value (allowable trailer GVWR)
"""
@anvil.server.callable
def get_truck_specifications():
  
  # Get data from 'truck_inputs' data table
  brand = get_brand()
  model = get_model()
  year = get_year()
  engine = get_engine()
  drive = get_drive()
  axle = get_axle()
  payload = int(get_payload())
  passengers = int(get_passengers())
  cargo = int(get_cargo())
  hitch = int(get_hitch())
  
  # Get data from 'truck_specifications' data table
  gcwr = int(get_gcwr(brand, model, year, engine, drive, axle))
  gvwr_truck = int(get_gvwr_truck(brand, model, year, engine, drive, axle))
  base_weight = int(get_base_weight(gvwr_truck, payload))
  gvw = base_weight + passengers + cargo + hitch
  value = gcwr - gvw
  return value
```

Here is a screen shot that shows an example of the data table...

['Truck Specifications' data table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vOoH.png)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The documentation string should go _after_ the `def` line.

Comment: `gwcr_row` is `None`. This means that your query returns no results.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the columns in the data table were not labeled correctly after I implemented an uploader (versus manually adding data). After re-labeling, the problem is solved.